# HTMl + CSS - Fix number of columns in a table

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im having trouble with building a table in responsive design.
Is there an easy way to set the number of columns for a table with CSS so that I dont need to set the < tr > tag manually and it puts just for example 4 elements in each row? I need this because I want to lower that number in phone design for making the elements bigger.

Comment: You should not be using tables for this.

Comment: If it needs to be a table .. take a look at http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: Looks very similar to what I want, thank you! But what would you suggest instead of tables?

Comment: use <div> @AntonKan here's a quick article http://www.codemiles.com/html-examples/creating-table-using-div-tag-t8639.html